# Vidalia shows 4 nodes, instead of usual 3

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vidalia

I observed connected nodes in circuits in Vidalia standalone gui "network map". Some connections have 4 nodes instead of usual 3, does Tor do that automatically or is this a problem that will make unique fingerprint?

Comment: I read somewhere (can't remember where) that Tor chooses at least three nodes. Everywhere else says three, which makes me think the former statement may have just been gobbledygook.

Comment: Also JFYI, Vidalia is dead, hasn't been maintained for years and you shouldn't probably use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue and happens regularly with hidden services, less regularly but still often when accessing services on an unusual port and even less frequently during regular usage. It is nothing to be concerned about, your Tor client just decided it either needed a four-hop path because the fourth node wasn't chosen by itself or because extending a circuit was cheaper than building a new circuit from scratch.